# Xcode debug, step out not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I have only one breakpoint in code.
After I run my app in debug mode, debug navigates me to my breakpoint, and then I clicked "step out".
Expected result: application should continue to run.
What I have: its navigate me to strange place

[image]

**UPDATE:** If I have 2 breakpoints in my app, after first breakpoint it should navigate me to second. But still it navigates me to this strange place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method was called by code that you don't have the source for, this will happen - Apple performs the "step out" and you end up inside one of Apple's libraries.

You can keep hitting "step out" until you end up back in one of your own libraries - or, if your code is encased in Apple code (e.g. it's being called from UIKit), there may be no encapsulating code that belongs to you.

Read the stack on the LHS to check.

NB: the stack on LHS now *BY DEFAULT IS ALWAYS SLIGHTLY INCORRECT*, Apple added a "feature" where it gives a "pretty" stack with lots missing. This is often helpful, but if you don't notice it happening, it can be very confusing. You need to grab the slider at bottom of LHS of screen and drag all the way to one side to see the "true" stack.

Answer (score 1):

Don't press step out, use the continue button (something like a  play button). This will continue your program.